# CSS resize image height with changing window height

Tags: html, css, image

I'm working on a webpage which contains 2 div-blocks, both with a width of 50%. On the left side is text, on the right side is an image. Both contents are centered in the middle of the div-blocks. With CSS I got so far that when I resize my Browser Window, the image resizes, too. But it does only so if I resize the width. If I resize only the height, the image size doesn't change. It just stays the same. That causes the image to overflow. However, at least until a minimum-height is reached I want the image size to react to the browser height, too.

To show what I mean I made the background-color of the right div-block white and resized my Browser Window. Here's how it looks like with full window size:

[image: Big Browser Window size]

Now with a small window width:

[image: Small Browser Window Width]

And with a small window height:

[image: Small Browser Window Height]

**CSS-Code**

```
<style type="text/css">
   html, body {
      height: 100%;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      background-color: black;
   }

   .half-window-left {
      width: 50%;
      height: 100%;
      float: left;
      background-color: black;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
   }

   .title {
      margin: 0 auto;
      align-self: center;
      font-family: "Optima", Arial, sans-serif;
      font-size: 60px;
      color: white;
   }

   .half-window-right {
      width: 50%;
      height: 100%;
      float: right;
      background-color: white;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      overflow: hidden;
   }

   .div-hexagon-center {
      left: -10%;
      width: 50%;
      height: auto;
      margin: 0 auto;
      align-self: center;
      position: relative;
      display: flex;
      object-fit: contain;
      background-color: black;
      overflow-y: hidden;
   }

   img {
      display: block;
      min-width: 30%;
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
   }
</style>
```

**HTML-Code**

```
<div class="half-window-left">
   <table class="title">
       <tr>
           <td><b style="color: #62B7F4;">W</b>ater</td>
       </tr>
       <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
       <tr>
           <td><b style="color: #31D994;">B</b>iosphere</td>
       </tr>
       <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
       <tr>
           <td><b style="color: #DAC081;">E</b>arth</td>
       </tr>
   </table>
</div>
<div class="half-window-right">
   <div class="div-hexagon-center">
       <img src="tripple-hexagon.png"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

I guess I also screwed the CSS-code a bit because of so much testing around. There are dozends of possible solutions out there, I tried most of them but without much success.

Answer (score 0):

if you want the height of the image to be responsive to the height of the screen, you can set a percentage height on the image, with a max and min height set so the image never gets too big or too small. something like this:

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.img {
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url(https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg);
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 400px;
  min-width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 400px;
  min-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class='img'>

</div>
```

I went with a div with a background-image so I can also use the background-size css property set to 'cover', but it's up to you whether you need that or not. Also, you'll want to play with the percentages and max/min values to fit your needs

Comment: That helped in so far as to improve the overall CSS-Code. It's shorter now. However, now there is no resizing, neither in width, nor in height. Here's a screen: https://imgur.com/Jxzp1VA

Comment: maybe something else is wrong? If you run the example I posted by clicking 'run code snippet' and then clicking 'go to fullscreen' it should resize. Unfortunately I don't have time to read through all of your code so I can't debug your issue more closely right now